# Get Tweets from Twitter hbc API

Tags: java, twitter, twitter-hbc

```
public class TwitterStreamImpl implements TwitterStream {

    public void setUpStream() throws InterruptedException {
        final String consumerKey = getTwitterCredentials().get(0).toString();
        final String consumerSecret = getTwitterCredentials().get(1).toString();
        final String token = getTwitterCredentials().get(2).toString();
        final String secret = getTwitterCredentials().get(3).toString();

        BlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>(10000);
        StatusesFilterEndpoint endpoint = new StatusesFilterEndpoint();
        // add some track terms
        endpoint.trackTerms(Lists.newArrayList("twitterapi", "#yolo", "trump", "donald", "lol"));

        Authentication auth = new OAuth1(consumerKey, consumerSecret, token, secret);
        // Authentication auth = new BasicAuth(username, password);

        // Create a new BasicClient. By default gzip is enabled.
        BasicClient client = new ClientBuilder()
                .hosts(Constants.STREAM_HOST)
                .endpoint(endpoint)
                .authentication(auth)
                .processor(new StringDelimitedProcessor(queue))
                .build();

        // Establish a connection
        client.connect();

        // Do whatever needs to be done with messages
        for (int msgRead = 0; msgRead < 1000; msgRead++) {
          if (client.isDone()) {
            System.out.println("Client connection closed unexpectedly: " + client.getExitEvent().getMessage());
            break;
          }

          String msg = queue.poll(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          if (msg == null) {
            System.out.println("Did not receive a message in 5 seconds");
          } else {
            System.out.println(msg);
          }
        }

        client.stop();
    }

    /**
     * Reads twitterStup.txt from C:/Users/"user"/documents/ and returns them as
     * an array
     * 
     * @return Twitter Api Credentials
     */
    private ArrayList getTwitterCredentials() {
        BufferedReader in;
        String str;
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("*******"));

            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                list.add(str);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

The console log says:

```
Did not receive a message in 5 seconds
```

And it says that every five seconds.
I want to "sysout" (live) every tweet, that has one of the endpoint trackTerms in it. But there is no error or something similar.
Is there a problem with the proxy perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is working, as it is at the time. The problem was the proxy. Because I've been in the office-network, the connection to the stream wasn't possible. So i tried it with my own notebook, guess what, it worked.